# Bootstrap - fit image to div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, image, resize

The size of image that fits into the div is 800 X 600 pixels. But some of the old images (portrait paintings) I have are 300 X 400 pixels. If I change the image size they will lose resolution. Instead, I would like to change div size. Is that possible? If not, is there a workaround?
I am providing code to be able to run the example as suggested

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  color: #666666;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
a {
  color: #18d26e;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
  color: #18d36e;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* Back to top button */
.back-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  background: #18d26e;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  transition: background 0.5s;
  z-index: 11;
}
.back-to-top i {
  padding-top: 12px;
  color: #fff;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .back-to-top {
    bottom: 15px;
  }
}
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Header
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
#header {
  padding: 30px 0;
  height: 92px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  z-index: 997;
}
#header.header-scrolled {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  padding: 20px 0;
  height: 72px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
#header #logo {
  float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  #header #logo {
    padding-left: 60px;
  }
}
#header #logo h1 {
  font-size: 34px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
#header #logo h1 a, #header #logo h1 a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-left: 4px solid #18d26e;
}
#header #logo img {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #header #logo h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
  }
  #header #logo img {
    max-height: 40px;
  }
}
img.scaled {
  width: 100%;
}


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Navigation Menu
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Nav Menu Essentials */
.nav-menu, .nav-menu * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.nav-menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
.nav-menu li {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.nav-menu > li {
  float: left;
}
.nav-menu li:hover > ul,
.nav-menu li.sfHover > ul {
  display: block;
}
.nav-menu ul ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
.nav-menu ul li {
  min-width: 180px;
}

/* Nav Menu Arrows */
.sf-arrows .sf-with-ul {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.sf-arrows .sf-with-ul:after {
  content: "\f107";
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.sf-arrows ul .sf-with-ul:after {
  content: "\f105";
}
/* Nav Meu Container */
#nav-menu-container {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  #nav-menu-container {
    padding-right: 60px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #nav-menu-container {
    display: none;
  }
}
/* Nav Meu Styling */
.nav-menu a {
  padding: 0 8px 10px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: none;
}

.nav-menu li:hover > a, .nav-menu > .menu-active > a {
  color: #18d26e;
}
.nav-menu > li {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.nav-menu ul {
  margin: 4px 0 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(127, 137, 161, 0.25);
  background: #fff;
}
.nav-menu ul li {
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.nav-menu ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333;
  transition: 0.3s;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: none;
}
.nav-menu ul li:hover > a {
  color: #18d26e;
}
.nav-menu ul ul {
  margin: 0;
}
/* Mobile Nav Toggle */
#mobile-nav-toggle {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: none;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#mobile-nav-toggle i {
  color: #fff;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #mobile-nav-toggle {
    display: inline;
  }
}
/* Mobile Nav Styling */
#mobile-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 18px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 998;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  left: -260px;
  width: 260px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
#mobile-nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#mobile-nav ul li {
  position: relative;
}
#mobile-nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 22px 10px 15px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
#mobile-nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
#mobile-nav ul li li {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
#mobile-nav ul .menu-has-children i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}
#mobile-nav ul .menu-has-children i.fa-chevron-up {
  color: #18d26e;
}
#mobile-nav ul .menu-has-children li a {
  text-transform: none;
}
#mobile-nav ul .menu-item-active {
  color: #18d26e;
}
#mobile-body-overly {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 997;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  display: none;
}
/* Mobile Nav body classes */
body.mobile-nav-active {
  overflow: hidden;
}
body.mobile-nav-active #mobile-nav {
  left: 0;
}
body.mobile-nav-active #mobile-nav-toggle {
  color: #fff;
}
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Sections
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Sections Header
--------------------------------*/
.section-header h3 {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #111;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.section-header h3::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #ddd;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: calc(50% - 60px);
}

.section-header h3::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #18d26e;
  bottom: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 20px);
}

.section-header p {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  color: #333;
}

/* Section with background
--------------------------------*/
.section-bg {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

/


/* Portfolio Section
--------------------------------*/
#portfolio {
  padding: 60px 0;
}

#portfolio #portfolio-flters {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px 0 35px 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

#portfolio #portfolio-flters li {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #666666;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#portfolio #portfolio-flters li:hover, #portfolio #portfolio-flters li.filter-active {
  background: #18d26e;
  color: #fff;
}

#portfolio #portfolio-flters li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-wrap {
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-wrap:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item {
  position: relative;
  height: 360px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item figure {
  background: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 240px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item figure:hover img {
  opacity: 0.4;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item figure .link-preview, #portfolio .portfolio-item figure .link-details {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item figure .link-preview i, #portfolio .portfolio-item figure .link-details i {
  padding-top: 6px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #333;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item figure .link-preview:hover, #portfolio .portfolio-item figure .link-details:hover {
  background: #18d26e;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item figure .link-preview:hover i, #portfolio .portfolio-item figure .link-details:hover i {
  color: #fff;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item figure .link-preview {
  left: calc(50% - 38px);
  top: calc(50% - 18px);
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item figure .link-details {
  right: calc(50% - 38px);
  top: calc(50% - 18px);
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item figure:hover .link-preview {
  visibility: visible;
  left: calc(50% - 44px);
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item figure:hover .link-details {
  visibility: visible;
  right: calc(50% - 44px);
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-info {
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-info h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-info h4 a {
  color: #333;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-info h4 a:hover {
  color: #18d26e;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-info p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #b8b8b8;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <meta content="" name="keywords">
    <meta content="" name="description">
    <!-- Favicons -->
    <link href="img/favicon.png" rel="icon">
    <link href="img/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i|Montserrat:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS File -->
    <link href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Libraries CSS Files -->
    <link href="lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="lib/animate/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="lib/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="lib/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="lib/lightbox/css/lightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Main Stylesheet File -->
    <link href="css/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
       <main id="main">
        <section id="portfolio" class="section-bg">
            <div class="container">
                <header class="section-header">
                    <h3 class="section-title">Our Portfolio</h3>
                </header>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <ul id="portfolio-flters">
                            <li data-filter="*" class="filter-active">All</li>
                            <li data-filter=".filter-app">App</li>
                            <li data-filter=".filter-card">Card</li>
                            <li data-filter=".filter-web">Web</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row portfolio-container">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-app wow fadeInUp">
                        <div class="position-relative">

                            <figure>
                                <img src="img/portfolio/app1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                                <a href="img/portfolio/app1.jpg" data-lightbox="portfolio" data-title="App 1" class="link-preview align-self-lg-center scaled" title="Preview"><i class="ion ion-eye scaled"></i></a>
                                <a href="img/portfolio/app1.jpg" data-lightbox="portfolio" data-title="App 1" class="link-preview"><i class="ion ion-android-open align-self-lg-center scaled"></i></a>
                                <figcaption> figure caption...</figcaption>
                            </figure>

                            <div class="portfolio-info">
                                <h4><a href="#">App 1</a></h4>
                                <p>App</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-app wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                        <div class="portfolio-wrap">
                            <figure>
                                <img src="img/portfolio/image2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                                <a href="img/portfolio/image2.jpg" class="link-preview" data-lightbox="portfolio" data-title="App 2" title="Preview"><i class="ion ion-eye"></i></a>
                                <a href="#" class="link-details" title="More Details"><i class="ion ion-android-open"></i></a>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-web wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.1s">
                        <div class="portfolio-wrap">
                            <figure>
                                <img src="img/portfolio/web3.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                                <a href="img/portfolio/web3.jpg" class="link-preview" data-lightbox="portfolio" data-title="Web 3" title="Preview"><i class="ion ion-eye"></i></a>
                                <a href="#" class="link-details" title="More Details"><i class="ion ion-android-open"></i></a>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="portfolio-info">
                                <h4><a href="#">Web 3</a></h4>
                                <p>Web</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-app wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                        <div class="portfolio-wrap">
                            <figure>
                                <img src="img/portfolio/app2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                                <a href="img/portfolio/app2.jpg" class="link-preview" data-lightbox="portfolio" data-title="App 2" title="Preview"><i class="ion ion-eye"></i></a>
                                <a href="#" class="link-details" title="More Details"><i class="ion ion-android-open"></i></a>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="portfolio-info">
                                <h4><a href="#">App 2</a></h4>
                                <p>App</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-card wow fadeInUp">
                        <div class="portfolio-wrap">
                            <figure>
                                <img src="img/portfolio/card2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                                <a href="img/portfolio/card2.jpg" class="link-preview" data-lightbox="portfolio" data-title="Card 2" title="Preview"><i class="ion ion-eye"></i></a>
                                <a href="#" class="link-details" title="More Details"><i class="ion ion-android-open"></i></a>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="portfolio-info">
                                <h4><a href="#">Card 2</a></h4>
                                <p>Card</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-web wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.1s">
                        <div class="portfolio-wrap">
                            <figure>
                                <img src="img/portfolio/web2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                                <a href="img/portfolio/web2.jpg" class="link-preview" data-lightbox="portfolio" data-title="Web 2" title="Preview"><i class="ion ion-eye"></i></a>
                                <a href="#" class="link-details" title="More Details"><i class="ion ion-android-open"></i></a>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="portfolio-info">
                                <h4><a href="#">Web 2</a></h4>
                                <p>Web</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-app wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                        <div class="portfolio-wrap">
                            <figure>
                                <img src="img/portfolio/app3.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                                <a href="img/portfolio/app3.jpg" class="link-preview" data-lightbox="portfolio" data-title="App 3" title="Preview"><i class="ion ion-eye"></i></a>
                                <a href="#" class="link-details" title="More Details"><i class="ion ion-android-open"></i></a>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="portfolio-info">
                                <h4><a href="#">App 3</a></h4>
                                <p>App</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-card wow fadeInUp">
                        <div class="portfolio-wrap">
                            <figure>
                                <img src="img/portfolio/card1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                                <a href="img/portfolio/card1.jpg" class="link-preview" data-lightbox="portfolio" data-title="Card 1" title="Preview"><i class="ion ion-eye"></i></a>
                                <a href="#" class="link-details" title="More Details"><i class="ion ion-android-open"></i></a>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="portfolio-info">
                                <h4><a href="#">Card 1</a></h4>
                                <p>Card</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-card wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.1s">
                        <div class="portfolio-wrap">
                            <figure>
                                <img src="img/portfolio/card3.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                                <a href="img/portfolio/card3.jpg" class="link-preview" data-lightbox="portfolio" data-title="Card 3" title="Preview"><i class="ion ion-eye"></i></a>
                                <a href="#" class="link-details" title="More Details"><i class="ion ion-android-open"></i></a>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="portfolio-info">
                                <h4><a href="#">Card 3</a></h4>
                                <p>Card</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-web wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                        <div class="portfolio-wrap">
                            <figure>
                                <img src="img/portfolio/web1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                                <a href="img/portfolio/web1.jpg" class="link-preview" data-lightbox="portfolio" data-title="Web 1" title="Preview"><i class="ion ion-eye"></i></a>
                                <a href="#" class="link-details" title="More Details"><i class="ion ion-android-open"></i></a>
                            </figure>
                            <div class="portfolio-info">
                                <h4><a href="#">Web 1</a></h4>
                                <p>Web</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>

    <a href="#" class="back-to-top"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
    <!-- JavaScript Libraries -->
    <script src="lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/easing/easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/superfish/hoverIntent.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/superfish/superfish.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/wow/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/waypoints/waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/counterup/counterup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/lightbox/js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/touchSwipe/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Contact Form JavaScript File -->
    <script src="contactform/contactform.js"></script>
    <!-- Template Main Javascript File -->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you expect any sensible answers, you need to post a **complete** `code snippet` (HTML, CSS & JavaScript including CDN links) that allows *replicating your issue exactly*. Otherwise, any answers would be based on guesswork and you want to avoid that. Edit your question and post your **complete** current `code snippet` there at the bottom by clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon.

Comment: The image does fit into the div perfectly using your current code snippet. That's why I posted that comment above.

Comment: @WebDevBooster - I have tried adding html and css files.

Comment: Not files. You can't add files. You need to add `CODE`. How hard can it be?